# Preselecting state of UISegmentControl based on bool

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

New to programming but didn't see this addressed in other posts.

Working in Swift

I am passing the result of a two segment UISegmentControl as a BOOL between view controllers.  When I return to the initial view controller, the UISegementControl is reverting to its initial state (Zero position).  I want to pass back the BOOL value, which I have done through prepareForSegue, and then pre-select the value based on that BOOL.

My intent is that if the user chooses segment 1, when the user goes back to the VC, it will still be chosen as segment 1 (it is reverting back to segment 0).

What do I use to change the selected segment of the UISegementControl in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Add UISegementControl in viewDidLoad and set selectedSegmentIndex with your bool in viewWillAppear??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**selectedSegmentIndex**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISegmentedControl/selectedSegmentIndex) property for doing this:

```
if yourBool == true
{
   yourSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
}
else
{
   yourSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I tried this before but didn't work. I'll look for an error in my code on calling it. I'm sure it is my error somewhere.

Comment: It just isn't changing the segment control. I'm passing the bool through prepareforsegue from the first vc and then calling the func above in viewwillappear but it doesn't seem to change the uisegementcontrol when I reload the second vc. Maybe a stack issue?

Comment: @nyc2pdx: Looks like some allocation issue, looks like you have multiple instances and using wrong instance value.

Comment: Thanks-you are probably right. I will review and do some break points to find out the problem. Thanks the for the help. I'll update when I find the error. Likely I will find it and say "how could I have missed that?!"